# Not able to change a TextView content from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, string, broadcastreceiver, getter-setter

I am trying to get string from a BroadcastReceiver which will set the content of a TextView in my activity.

I have are two Java classes

1. MainActivity: It has the TextView whose text I want to change.
2. batteryinfo: It extends BroadcastReceiver. This class has the
   method that returns the custom String (getString())

Here is the code of MainActivity

```
package com.example.batteryhealth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    BatteryManager bm;
    TextView health;
    String string;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        health=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //status=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        batteryinfo bmc= new batteryinfo(bm,string);
        this.registerReceiver(bmc, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

        health.setText(bmc.gethealth());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

Here is the code of batteryinfo:

```
package com.example.batteryhealth;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.BatteryManager;

public class batteryinfo extends BroadcastReceiver{

    BatteryManager bm;
    String health;

    public batteryinfo(BatteryManager b,String hea) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.bm=b;
        this.health=hea;

    }




    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i= intent.getIntExtra(bm.EXTRA_HEALTH, 0);

        boolean s=true;


        if(s=i==bm.BATTERY_HEALTH_COLD)
        {
           health="cold";

        }
        else if(s=i==bm.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD)
        {
            health="good";
        }
        else if (s=i==bm.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT)

        {
            health="overheat"       ;
        }
        else if (s=i==bm.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE)
        {
            health="overvolteage";
        }

    }

    public String gethealth()
    {
        return health;
    }

}
```

If I create a nested class (which also extends BroadcastReciver) in the MainActivity the code works fine, but after creating a separate class it does not work and my TextView is empty.

Comment: Put a `Log.i` in `onReceive`, and see if broadcast is received or not?

Comment: @MysticMagic is right. We need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Register a new broadcast receiver inside your MainActivity and then send broadcast to your MainActivity class from your batteryinfo class and change the text in your MainActivity's receiver